# how to read input data from /BOBF/IF_FRW_DETERMINATION~EXECUTE in cds

Tags: odata, abap, cds

I have redefined  busssiness object in cds for /BOBF/IF_FRW_DETERMINATION~EXECUTE method ,
i want to read  data which is coming from front end in /BOBF/IF_FRW_DETERMINATION~EXECUTE method .
In front end i have called update method .

Comment: Please provide a minimal example  as code such that others can follow your problem.

Comment: Are you working with a draft-enabled BOPF application? if so, you can provide detailed information .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  /BOBF/IF_FRW_DETERMINATION~EXECUTE method i used it's  'io_read' interface method

"retrieve" to get the data.

CALL METHOD io_read->retrieve

EXPORTING

```
         iv_node                   =  is_ctx-node_key
         it_key                    =  it_key
        IMPORTING
           et_data       = lt_root.
```

where lt_root is

DATA :lt_root TYPE TABLE OF zrik. (zrik is root structure of project, i found it while debugging )

i found a similar blog  explaining crud operation using bobf

https://blogs.sap.com/2019/08/29/abap-fiori-elements-adding-bopf-create-remove-update-delete-crud-actions-to-cds-views-building-from-scratch-walkthrough-part-2/